# Including a Search Plugin in my Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, plugins, firefox-addon, search-engine

I am developing a Firefox Extension (Firefox 3.6 and up) and i would like, when the user installs my extension to:

1. Add my own Search Engine to the list of available Search Engines in Firefox.
2. Change the default search engine to my new installed search engine.

How strange that it is, I couldn't find much help in the Mozilla Developer Network and Googeling it...

Thanks.
Aviv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your search plugin definition in the searchplugins/ subdirectory of your extension (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bundles). Set browser.search.selectedEngine to the name of your engine to make it the default.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. Just to make sure people know how to do it: //netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
  var prefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
  prefs.setCharPref('browser.search.selectedEngine', 'your search engine name');