# Firefox 6 Extension and Search Plugin bundle does not work

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, search-engine, firefox6

Adding a Search Plugin for Firefox Via Extension is done using bundles, putting your .xml OpeSearch in /searchplugins/ directory and Firefox will automatically add them when the Extension is installed.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bundles and also my own question [Including a Search Plugin in my Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678740/including-a-search-plugin-in-my-firefox-extension)

Well, it worked fine, until i started using Firefox 6. It seems that Firefox 6 does not read the /searchplugins/ directory anymore and does not add the Search Plugin. It might be also Firefox 4 and 5, i jumped from 3.6 to 6 directly.

Any idea if this is a bug in Firefox 6?
Any idea how to by pass it and install the SearchPlugin Anyway?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to be asked on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Gweebz: No, it is a development question all right. Only problem being that I don't know about any changes related to search plugins in Firefox 6.

Comment: @Wladimir - My mistake. After reading the question again, it is obvious to me now that it is a development question; I must have mis-understood it originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only relevant difference between Firefox 3.6 and Firefox 6 (Firefox 4 actually) is that by default extensions are no longer unpacked on installation, instead they are placed into user's profile as XPI files. This works for most extensions but particularly search plugins won't work from an XPI file. Which is why you have to [add the `unpack` flag to your `install.rdf` file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#unpack):

```
<Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
   <em:id>...</em:id>
   <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
   ...
</Description>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's look like a direction ... but it didn't worked for me ... alas no search provider was added although the xpi was unpacked